# How to merge two tables in Access using SQL. Two tables have several common columns but also have several columns not in common

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to merge two tables using query in MSAccess using SQL.

Table 1 has following columns:

```
ID, address, rent, tax, basement, garage
```

Table 2 has following colums:

`ID, address, rent, price, sold_date`

In the final output, I want

`ID, address, rent, tax, price, basement, garage, sold_date` together.

The IDs in two table are not same at all. It's kind of like concatenating two tables together with same columns' name link together and leave different columns in the different columes.

I tried using full outer join in `MSAccess` which is already tricky but require two tables has same structures.

`select * from Table1
 left join Table2 
 On Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
 Union 
 select * from Table1 
 right join Table2 
 On Table1.ID = Table2.ID`

Above codes is my current code which retrive the data without merge the two tables together with the same columns name. This is learned from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6

The output is like:

`Table1.ID, Table1.address, Table1.rent, Table1.price, Table1.sold_date, Table2.ID, Table2.address, Table2.rent, Table2.price, Table2.sold_date`

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Full outer join is what you want.  Can you include your current SQL code?

Comment: I have already include the code, please take a look. Thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

You may simulate a full outer join in Access using a union of a left and a right join:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.address, t1.rent, t1.tax, t2.price, t2.basement, t2.garage, t2.sold_date 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.ID, t1.address, t1.rent, t1.tax, t2.price, t2.basement, t2.garage, t2.sold_date
FROM Table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this piece of code, but it lost the IDs, address, in table2 in the final output. I can do it by modifying the second select into t2.ID, t2.address. But it's like we do the mapping by ourselves not by the machine to connect two same columns together

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to generate all the ids and use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from ((select id from Table1
       union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
       select id from table2
      ) as i left join
      Table1 as t1
      on i.ID = t1.ID 
     ) left join
     Table2 as t2
     on i.ID = t2.ID ;
```

However, Tim's solution should also work.  In some versions of MS Access, you may need to replace the `UNION` with view.

Comment: @zjluoxiao . . . Why not?

Comment: It pop out "no join type could be used", have you tried that code in MSAccess?

Comment: @zjluoxiao . . . As mentioned in the answer, the problem might be the `union`.  That might require a view because of MS Access limitations.